# Why am I seeing the error "the system cannot find the file specified" in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

[image: screenshot]

I am getting an error "the system cannot find the file specified" in Visual Studio C++ when I try to run my program.

Comment: It says you did not define `main()` so the build failed and there is nothing to run.

Answer (score 1):

You pressed F5 to start the program.

The code was compiled.

The linker failed because it couldn't find `int main()`

This means there was no program to run.

To fix it you need to define a function called `main`* that will look like this:

```
int main (void)
{
    // Call the function that you think starts your program, i.e.
    Bob();
    wprintf(L"Press enter to exit\n");
    return fgetc(stdin);
}
```

The press F7 to make sure it compiles.

Once it has compiled you can use F5 again.

*All C, C++ programs have to have a function called `main` its the first user visible function that is called.  All your code will be called from within main.
Some times main is 'hidden', such as `wmain` of MFC GUIs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, because you have not given enough information.

Nevertheless, at first I would check the compiling options of the solution and projects for any wrong or missing paths.

If that would not fix the issue, I would check if I have access to all the directories.

Besides, I would avoid using space in any names or paths, because those can cause issues too. I would use [camel case notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) instead.